# Is there enough money in one playthrough to buy everything?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Assuming I wanted all mods, armor, model ships, and powers, etc.  Is there enough credits in one play-through to buy everything?  In other words, is there a source of credits in the game that's renewable?

Comment: Aren't the N7 missions (the ones that take place on the Multiplayer maps) repeatable?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do it without relying on multiplayer

Comment: The N7 missions aren't *multiplayer*, they're just side quests that happen to use the same *maps as multiplayer.*

Comment: Just checked. They aren't repeatable. So no, that's not a source of cash.

Comment: Short Answer to your question -- Nope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, no. I've collected about 600000 credits altogether, and the Spectre Requisitions weapons cost more than that. You'd need about twice that to buy everything, and I doubt i've missed half of all possible credits.

Comment: what about the repeatable missions @Raven mentioned?

Comment: @yx. I was asking if they *were* repeatable; I don't know.

Comment: The only hard number I have is that doing all of the various fetch quests around the Citadel will earn you a shade under 200,000 credits.

Comment: They aren't repeatable.

Comment: And money in multiplayer doesn't carry over to single player.

Comment: Is it possible after 2? Seems like 3 are needed from my experience. I finished playthrough 2 and got almost everything but the Spectre weapons, which needed another playthrough all of their own

Comment: @Rarity were you super-thorough in collecting everything in each location and doing every quest?

Comment: I was the first playthrough, and double my first playthrough's money wouldn't have bought everything. Second playthrough I skipped citadel missions mostly, but was still over 600,000 credits short after two playthroughs