# What is the most expensive item in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What is the most expensive item or items in Mass Effect 3? Since you [can't buy everything in the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54445/1561), I'm wondering if I should be saving my credits up for something awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specre Requisitions on the Citadel has the most expensive items, the Black Widow sniper rifle and the M-11 Wraith shotgun for 250,000 credits each. IF you want, you can pay 10% more via the Normandy, bringing the cost up to 275,000 credits.

After those, the most expensive items are the M- Paladin pistol (200,000 credits) and the armor sets (50,000 apiece).

Most other items are only a few thousand. Also, [as I previously noted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55440/11920), none of the Spectre weapons are THAT great except for the Sniper Rifle.

Answer (score -1):

I play as an infiltrator and the most expensive one I have found is the market item in spectre office. The Black Widow sniper gun which cost around 2500000 credits.