# Is there a finite amount of money in ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there enough money in one playthrough to buy everything?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54445/is-there-enough-money-in-one-playthrough-to-buy-everything)

There was a finite amount of money in ME2, making it impossible to buy every single upgrade in one play through. How does this work in ME3? Can I earn enough money to buy every single thing in game, or do I need to play the game multiple times before I can have all upgrades?